# Prove that if in ring $R$ multiplications $xy$ and $yx$ are invertible, then elements $x$ and $y$ are also invertible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that if in ring $R$ multiplications $xy$ and $yx$ are invertible, then elements $x$ and $y$ are also invertible.

I found out that I could use $(a*b)^{-1}=b^{-1}*a^{-1}$, but I a not sure yet, how.

Comment: I've reinstated the question because an answer had been given in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

Well, by your hypothesis, there must be $s$ and $t$ such that $xyt=1$ and $syx=1$.

Do you see anything here that indicates $x$ is a unit?

Concluding the same thing for $y$ will be the same story.

Comment: Why do I even need the information that yx is an unit then?

Comment: So if $xys=1$ and $yxt=1$ then the inverse element for $x$ is $ys$ and for $y$ it is $xt$?

Comment: @Filippe If you only know that $xy$ is a unit, then $xyt=txy=1$. It is obvious that $yt$ is a right inverse for $x$, but you do not know, at that point, that $x$ is also *left* invertible. That's why you ned that $yx$ is invertible. So in your last comment, I would say "No, you are only half done. You have only shown that each one is invertible on one side."

Comment: @Filippe Also, if you are using the same notation as I am in your comment, there is no reason at the beginning to assume $yxt=1$ (as opposed to $xyt=1$) (Unless of course, you have been assuming all along that your ring is commutative.)

Comment: If the ring is commutatiove then $xyt=txy=ytx=1$ so $yt$ is a right and left inverse since the ring is commutative, same for $y$ right? @rschwieb

Comment: @Maths1999_ If the ring is commutative then there's nothing interesting to prove. Simply from $xy$ invertible you'd know $x$ and $y$ are invertible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\quad\ \ x\ invertible\:\iff\: \exists\,a,b\!:\,\ xa\,$ right-invertible, $\rm\ bx\:$ left-invertible

**Proof** $\ \ (\Rightarrow)\ \ $ Let $\rm\: a = 1 = b.\ \ (\Leftarrow)\ \ \ 1 = (xa)c = x(ac),\ \ 1 = d(bx) = (db)x$